# Annoying sand that gets into our house!

Tags: french-drain

We just bought a house and the top of the driveway has sand which we figured is where a french drain pipe is underground.  As of now, moving the french drain pipe is not in our budget but in a year or so, we hope to move it.  It is about 5 feet from our side door and we get sand in the house.  We would like to put pebbles or stone down on top of the sand but we are afraid of crushing the pipe.  What is recommended?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Those pipes can usually stand to be buried pretty deep.  but either way There would be no harm in removing some of the sand and replacng it with crushed rock or pebbles.